# Can a method receive an Array or Iterable?

Tags: java

The for loop (as foreach) accepts arrays or iterables, is there an input type that covers both, or do I have to write an overloaded method? Can I have in Java:

```
public void serialize (ArrayOrIterable xxx){
  for (Object x: xxx) {
     x.doSomething()
  }
}
```

Or is my only choice having repeated code?

```
public void serialize (Object[] xxx){
  for (Object x: xxx) {
     x.doSomething()
  }
}

public void serialize (Iterable xxx){
  for (Object x: xxx) {
     x.doSomething()
  }
}
```

**EDIT FOR CONCLUSIONS**

Even better, the class structure is actually an abstract class and its implementation so I can define the behaviour for arrays in the asbtract class and any implementations need only have one method overwritten.

```
public abstract class Serializer {

    public final void serialize(Object[] input) {
         serialize(Arrays.ssList(input));
    }

    public abstract void serialize(Iterable input);

}
```

Comment: I am sure you tried your approach. Did it work?

Comment: aww... oks. I cannot try it rigth now or I would have checked it myself... :)

Comment: If you wrap your array as list you can use one method.. But arrays cannot be used with Iterator

Comment: I would only keep the Iterable one. People generally use collections and not arrays, and if they do, they just need to wrap their array into a list to be able to call your method.

Comment: Interesting point. However array being a primitive type... seems quite common in the code base I'm working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java, unfortunately, doesn't have a reasonable syntax of doing this, as `Iterable`s and arrays are discrete types. However, you can improve the current code are remove the duplication of the `doSomething()` calls by wrapping the array with a `List` interface by calling `Arrays.asList`:

```
public void serialize (Object[] xxx){
  serialize (Arrays.asList(xxx));
}

public void serialize (Iterable xxx){
  for (Object x: xxx) {
     x.doSomething()
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll accpet it as soon as I can.

Comment: efficiency-wise it changes nothing (or almost) right? just adds a little constant, no extra O(n) added... the wrapping is constant?

Comment: Indeed - the wrapping is a (very) small constant, not an O(n) operation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have two distinct methods, since arrays don't implement `Iterable`.

However, you can still avoid repetition by wrapping the array as a list with `Arrays.asList()`:

```
public void serialize (Object[] xxx){
    serialize(Arrays.asList(xxx));
}

public serialize (Iterable xxx){
    for(Object x: xxx) {
       x.doSomething()
    } 
}
```

That way at least your logic is only handled in one discreet method.